# Primitive roots in $\mathbb{F}_7[x]/(x^2+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, primitive-roots

Are $2+x$ and $1+x$ primitive roots in $\mathbb{F}_7[x]/(x^2+1)$? I'm having trouble with the arithmetic associated with finding primitive roots.

Comment: We have $(1+x)^2=2x$, so $(1+x)^6=-x$, so $(1+x)^{12}=-1$. It follows that $1+x$ is not a primitive root.

Answer (score 2):

The field ${\Bbb F}_7[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ has $48$ non-zero elements.  We have
$$\eqalign{
  (1+x)^2&=1+2x+x^2=2x\cr
  (1+x)^3&=2x+2x^2=5+2x\cr
  (1+x)^4&=5+7x+2x^2=3\cr}$$
and so on.  Sooner or later you will find $(1+x)^n=1$.  If the **first** time this happens is when $n=48$, then $1+x$ is a primitive root.

There are some short cuts: the first value of $n$ must be a factor of $48$, so if you show that it is not $1,2,3,4,6,8,12,16$ or $24$ then it must be $48$.  And with a bit of thought you can see that it is only necessary to confirm that
$$(1+x)^{16}\ne1\quad\hbox{and}\quad (1+x)^{24}\ne1\ .$$